# Check if an In-App Purchased has already been purchased iphone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I submitted an iPhone app to the store that got approved, but some things with the inApp purchasing weren't working. The consequence is that the users that tried to install the inApp purchases were charged, and Apple has recorded that they already purchased the additional feature. I have fixed the issue, and I use NSUserDefaults to track whether or not a user has purchased the feature. The problem is the users that have already paid for it. Is there a way to check through Apple whether or not the feature has already been paid for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Restoring Transactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1) section of the In-App Purchase guide. Specifically:

> Store Kit provides built-in functionality to restore transactions for
>   non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions and free
>   subscriptions. To restore transactions, your application calls the
>   payment queue’s [restoreCompletedTransactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) method. The payment queue
>   sends a request to the App Store to restore the transctions. In
>   return, the App Store generates a new restore transaction for each
>   transaction that was previously completed.

If it is a consumable product (it shouldn't be) then I don't think there is a way to do it via Apple.